# Caching all the prepared statements in thread safe way

Tags: java, thread-safety, cache, singleton, guava

I have a below Singleton class where in my `getStatement` method, I populate a CHM by doing if check.

```
public class CacheHolder {
  private static final Map<String, PreparedStatement> holder = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  private static class Holder {
    private static final CacheHolder INSTANCE = new CacheHolder();
  }

  public static CacheHolder getInstance() {
    return Holder.INSTANCE;
  }

  private CacheHolder() {}

  public BoundStatement getStatement(String cql) {
    Session session = TestUtils.getInstance().getSession();
    PreparedStatement ps = holder.get(cql);
    if(ps == null) { // If "ps" is already present in cache, then we don't have to synchronize and make threads wait.
        synchronized {
          ps = holder.get(cql);
          if (ps == null) {
            ps = session.prepare(cql);
            holder.put(cql, ps);
          }
        }
    }
    return ps.bind();
  }
}
```

I am working with Cassandra and using datastax java driver so I have to re-use prepared statements and that's why I am caching it here. [Prepared Statement](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/da72105c2fcef8f0865047815df146cfbb2354e6/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/PreparedStatement.java) and [BoundStatement](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/da72105c2fcef8f0865047815df146cfbb2354e6/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/BoundStatement.java).

Is there any better way of making my `getStatement` method thread safe instead of using synchronized block like that? Any other data structure which might be thread safe for these kind of operations?

I am working with Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

```
public BoundStatement getStatement(String cql) {
    Session session = TestUtils.getInstance().getSession();
    PreparedStatement ps = holder.computeIfAbsent(cql, s -> session.prepare(s));
    return ps.bind();
}
```

According to `computeIfAbsent`'s [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-):

> The entire method invocation is performed atomically, so the function is applied at most once per key.

I also suggest that you declare `holder` of type `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of `Map` so that it becomes unambiguous for anyone reading `getStatement` that the synchronisation in `computeIfAbsent` is guaranteed.

Comment: I am still using Java 7. Can you provide an example how this would work in Java 7?

Comment: @david Too bad. I can't show you an equivalent since `computeIfAbsent` was introduced with Java 8. Can you update your post to state you're using Java 7 ?

Comment: ok just edited..

Comment: How about using `putIfAbsent` method of CHM?

Comment: @david with `putIfAbsent` the problem is that the value is not lazy-evaluated, i.e. `session.prepare(s)` will always be executed even if the value is already present in the map. On the other side, with `computeIfAbsent` the value is evaluated only if needed.

Comment: I believe `s -> session.prepare(s)` should be `s -> session.prepare(cql)`; but that's pretty nit-picky.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with the previous answer however computeIfAbsent() may block other threads while the computation is being performed

You can also do something like below (Compare-and-swap instead of locking, way more complex than the previous answer, so that answer may be the preferable one) -

```
public class CacheHolder {
private static final Map<String, PreparedStatement> holder = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private final PreparedStatement DUMMY_PS;

private static class Holder {
    private static final CacheHolder INSTANCE = new CacheHolder();
}

public static CacheHolder getInstance() {
    return Holder.INSTANCE;
}

private CacheHolder() {
    DUMMY_PS = //Create a dummy PS
}

public BoundStatement getStatement(String cql) {
    Session session = TestUtils.getInstance().getSession();
    PreparedStatement ps, prevValue;

    while(true) {
        ps = holder.get(cql);

        if(ps == null) {
            prevValue = holder.putIfAbsent(cql, DUMMY_PS);
            if (prevValue == null) { // the value before our putIfAbsent() call was null,
                                     // which means the spot was empty and we managed to book it with the DUMMY_VALUE
                                    // we should go ahead and put an entry there
                ps = session.prepare(cql);
                holder.put(cql, ps);
                return ps.bind();
            }
            else if (prevValue == DUMMY_PS) { //Some thread has already put the dummy value for this key, which means it is soon going to put the real thing in there
                continue;
            }
            else { //some thread had put the real thing in before we called putIfAbsent
                return prevValue.bind();
            }
        }
        if (ps == DUMMY_PS) {
            continue; //Some thread is soon going to put the real thing in there
        }
        else {
            return ps.bind();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Interesting approach. However, if preparing a statement takes some time, another thread looking for the same statement will use hog CPU time until DUMMY_PS is replaced with the real statement. That's very expensive and can cause a meltdown if a network hickup affects several threads at once.

Comment: True, that is an issue. Maybe other threads should wait on a conditional lock during that time.